# CakePHP - Custom Password

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, passwords

Recently I try to change the encoding of the password on CakePHP by directly adding a new file. Unfortunately I do not seem to connect, namely that her works perfectly with the class Simple in sha256

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array('Auth' => array(
    'authenticate'  => array(
        'Form'  => array(
            'fields'    => array('username'   => 'email','password' => 'password'),
            'passwordHasher'    => array(
                'className' => 'Custom'),
            'scope' => array('active'   => '1')
        )
    )
));
```

**UsersController(login)**

```
    App::uses('CustomPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class UsersController extends AppController{

    public function login()
    {

        $erreur = false;
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if(!empty($this->data)) {
                if(!$this->Auth->user('id')) {
                    if($this->Auth->login()) {
                        echo 'ok';
                    } else {
                        $erreur = "Identifiant incorrect.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $erreur = "Vous êtes déjà connecter.";
                }
            } else {
                $erreur = "Veuillez saisir vos identifiants";
            }
            $this->set(compact('erreur'));
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomPasswordHasher**

```
    App::uses('AbstractPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class CustomPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher {
    public function hash($password)
    {
        $before = substr(Configure::read('Security.salt'),0,43);
        $after = substr(Configure::read('Security.salt'),43,42);

        $chaine = $before.$password.$after;
        return hash("sha256",$chaine);

    }
    public function check($password, $email, $hashType = null) {
        $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
        $u = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'fields'        => array('user.password'),
            'conditions'    => array('user.email'   => $email)
        ));
        if($u) {
           return $this->hash($password) == $u['User']['password'];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

An idea where my problem might come?

Thank you !

Comment: What exactly happens. Are you trying to connect and render a view in the app, is your login attempt failing? give more specific information

Comment: I'm just trying to change the encoding of the password in a custom class Controller / Components / Auth. But after correctly configuring AppController we say that the code does not recognize the hash used. In case it could serve, here are the queries generated (hidden email address). The hash matches the stored database. 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/3b7e9d36e6c5450abec63a645d18fc42.png